# MS EXCEL - Conditional formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

A1 is an inputted value - for this example say 100

A2 is a formula - for this example say =A3/A1

A3 is a formula - for this example say =A2*A1

I would like to be able to input a value in either A2 or A3 while keeping the formulas in place. I'm looking for an "either/or" or "vice-versa" type command....

Thanks!

Comment: Your A2 and A3 formulas reference each other in a loop.

Comment: it looks like you would have a circular ref. error in your example. I do not think you can enter input to a cell that contains a formula. You would over write the formula once you type something in that cell.

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not work this way. You cannot enter a value in a cell and also have a formula in the cell.

The easiest would be to have A1, A2 and A3 for the manual input and calculate the result in a separate cell.

[image]

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2*A1,IF(ISNUMBER(A3),A3/A1,"Enter a value in either A2 or A3 and clear the other one."))
```

A more complex way would be to use VBA to calculate the result and write it into the respective cell. Paste the following code into the Sheet module (Right-Click the sheet > View Code)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A3")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
            [A3] = [A2] * [A1]

        Else
            [A2] = [A3] / [A1]
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```